# Is there a fast way of calculating 1000 Jacobians of a neural network?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, automatic-differentiation, gradienttape

For a numerical implementation I need to calculate the jacobian of a neural network with respect to the input, not the weights, but for 1000 instances in each iteration step that I do. For that I use the tensorflow GradientTape and it looks something like this:

```
def jacobian(model, unknown, known):
    tJac = time.time()
    with tf.GradientTape() as g:
        x = tf.constant(tf.convert_to_tensor(unknown, dtype=tf.float32))
        h = tf.constant(tf.convert_to_tensor(known, dtype=tf.float32))
        g.watch(x)
        y = tf.convert_to_tensor(model(tf.concat([x, h], 1)), dtype=tf.float32)
    jac = g.jacobian(y, x)
    print('Differentiation took %.3f sec' % (time.time()-tJac))
    return jac
```

So what I do is that I change the h 1000 times and each time I have to calculate the jacobian and hence have to call the predict of the neural network. This takes 0.16 sec per prediction resulting in 160 seconds since I do it 1000 times. Additionaly since this is only for one iterations step this is not feasible.

What I came up with is that I take my 1000 h instances and put them in a dataframe and then call predict only once. The problem now is that I do not have the ability to use the GradientTape because my code would looke something like this:

```
def jacobian(input, output):
    tJac = time.time()
    with tf.GradientTape() as g:
        x = tf.constant(tf.convert_to_tensor(input, dtype=tf.float32))
        g.watch(x)
        y = tf.convert_to_tensor(output, dtype=tf.float32)
    jac = g.jacobian(y, x)
    print('Differentiation took %.3f sec' % (time.time()-tJac))
    return jac
```

This simply results in None.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as written, your question seems to be asking for a recommendation regarding how to approach a solution, or asking us to provide a solution.  Since the former is a question most likely answered with an opinion and the latter is asking for us to provide a code solution.  Both of these cases are outside the scope of [so]

Comment: @itprorh66 Well, the question's intention was to look if anyone knows other ways to calculate the Jacobian or another way to use GradientTape since I'm not that familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different things out and reading more about automatic differentation and especially about GradientTape I came across the batch_jacobian function which does exactly what I was looking for.

Might be useful for other people that are also not that familiar with GradientTape.